# Redirect in PHP on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to redirect to another page in my PHP code on an AJAX call. The only thing I can seem to find online about this is to do it through JavaScript using `window.location.href = 'url';` but it does not work.

If I try to redirect using the `window.location.href` to `profile.php?user=person` then it has the url `localhost/profile.php?user=person` but if I type in the full URL for the redirect like `project/login/profile.php?user=person` then it stays on the same page. The `profile.php` page only echo's what who the user in the url is.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'processes/login.inc.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(res) {
            if(res != '4502') {
                var s = 'profile.php?user='+res;
                window.location.href = s;
            }

        }
    });
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../core/init.php');
$username = escape($_POST['ul']);
$password = escape($_POST['pl']);

$user = new User();

$login = $user->login($username, $password);

if($login) {
    // Redirect::to('../profile.php?user='.$username);
    echo $username;
} else {
    echo '4502';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you actually show the code you tried?

Comment: You can redirect to another page using php `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Scott I tried that, it won't redirect in the PHP while I am calling the PHP file via AJAX

Comment: ok so your trying to redirect the page in the middle of an AJAX request? Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910291/change-page-in-the-middle-of-ajax-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the full path, not only the php file and parameters, for example:

Change:

```
location.href = 'profile.php?user=person';
```

To:

```
location.href = '/login/profile.php?user=person';
```